Replacing a nested subscribe when getting multiple details from one initial call for ids
So I'm making a few calls to two back-end services, the first is to get the IDs of "big" items and the rest are separate calls to get the details of each "big" item using its ID.
I've looked at the concatMap(), switchMap(), mergeMap(), etc. from a great post here (and others):
Rxjs One Observable Feeding into Another
but I never seem to find where I can insert my loop to gather the data from an unknown number of calls to the second collection.
So here's the current way that works, but I want to move away from sub-in-sub.
Is this a job for Promises instead of RxJS?
loadWigitsDetailed() {
  this.wigitGetterService
    .fetchWigitIds({
      category: 'big'
    })
    .subscribe(response => {
      // say, 5 items returned.
      for (const oneWig of response.items) {
        this.detailedWigitInfoService.fetchWigitInfo({ id: oneWig.id })
          .subscribe(responseDetail => {
            wigitTable.addRow(responseDetail);
          });
      }
    });
}


You can definitely use Promises for this. But you could also use RxJS for this well. It can be done like this:
loadWigitsDetailed() {
  this.wigitGetterService.fetchWigitIds({ category: 'big' })
    .pipe(
      // Flatten the items array into a stream of items
      mergeMap(response => response.items),
      // For each item, fetch the detailed info
      mergeMap(eachWig => this.detailedWigitInfoService.fetchWigitInfo({ id: eachWig.id }))
    )
    .subscribe(responseDetail => {
      wigitTable.addRow(responseDetail);
    });
}


mergeMap should be used if the order is not important. But if you want things to go in a specific order, then you can replace mergeMap with concatMap.

I couldn't make this one work for me as it stood, but instead had to insert the 2nd mergeMap into a pipe() on the first.
pipe(mergeMap().pipe(mergeMap()))
This allowed me to do a null-check in-between. That said, even without the null-check I couldn't get this to work.

My approach involves using switchMap and forkJoin. First we use the observable to get all the ID fields, then we can use switchMap to switch from outer observable to inner observable. I then convert the array to an array of observables, which contain the details. Finally, we can use forkJoin which will parallely call the APIs and finally return the array with the details present, which we can assign to any variable and use it.
loadWigitsDetailed() {
  this.wigitGetterService
    .fetchWigitIds({
      category: 'big'
    }).pipe(
      switchMap((response: any) => {
        const apiArray$ = response.items.map((oneWig: any) => this.detailedWigitInfoService.fetchWigitInfo({ id: oneWig.id }))
        return forkJoin(apiArray$);
      })
    )
    .subscribe((widgetTable: any) => {
      this.widgetTable = widgetTable;
    });
}

